# how to pass schema names dynamically in grails 1.3.5 framework

Tags: grails

I want to copy table data from one schema to another schema. Once established the connection with source schema,table value is copied and then establish the connection with destination schema to save the data in destination table.

For this i need to pass the value of the schema dynamically to `Datasource.groovy` (`default_schema = ${someConfig.default_schema}`). Is there any other way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think [dataSource](http://grails.org/plugin/datasources) plugin is what you are looking for. Whit it you can setup a second datasource for your destination DB ad save objects in it.

Comment: Hi...I am not able to install datasources plugin in my project which is using grails 1.3.5 framework

Comment: Datasource plugins may work with 1.3.5. It will not work with grails >2.0 because multi datasource is already included in. Another possibility is to bypass hibernate layer and do raw sql querys as explained here http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL

Comment: For a single domain class, i need to connect 2 different schemas. Is it achievable in datasources plugin ?

Comment: I think you want to domain class, or at least identical domains but different packages